# I am trying to make an algorithm using if else function

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying to do some calcs using if else, but I can get it :

I have data obtained from a model, but this model tend to overestimate or underestimate the results depending of the total result. 
I am presenting a simple example:

```
d <- c(2,2,12,10, 24,30,50,55,60)
e <- c("red", "white", "red")
car <- data.frame(d,e)
names(car) <- c("carro","Color") # variable names

if(car$carro < 10){
car$carro <- car$carro * 0.5 ##50%
} else {
if((car$carro> 10) && (car$carro < 30)){
car$carro <- car$carro * 0.9 #90%
} else {
if(car$carro >30) {
car$carro <- car$carro * 1.50 #150%
} 
}
}
```

However, when I run the script it just assume the first condition (50%) for all the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @user13534 already said you were comparing a list to a number. Here's how I would do this:

```
d <- c(2,2,12,10, 24,30,50,55,60)
e <- c("red", "white", "red")
car <- data.frame(d,e)
names(car) <- c("carro","Color") # variable names

car$carro <- lapply(car$carro, function(x) ifelse(x < 10, x * 0.5, ifelse(x < 30 && x > 10, x * 0.9, x * 1.5)))
car

  carro Color
1     1   red
2     1 white
3  10.8   red
4    15   red
5  21.6 white
6    45   red
7    75   red
8  82.5 white
9    90   red
```

`ifelse` works great for this. For readability purposes always try to leverage `else if` conditionals when programming instead of containing an if condition within an else condition.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see any output in R console?

On my computer, it says:

```
    Warning message:
    In if (car$carro < 10) { :
      the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Basically, `car$carro` is a list equal to `d`. Since R doesn't know how to output TRUE/FALSE when comparing a list to a number, so it presumably uses the first list element, 2, to compare with 10 and output TRUE since 2 < 10. Then it just multiplies every element in `car$carro` by 0.5.

Answer (score 0):

In the post, condition is not clear.  For example, `car$carro < 10`, `(car$carro> 10) && (car$carro < 30)`, `car$carro >30` doesn't include the cases when 'carro' is 10 or 30.  I am assuming that the first condition is `car$carro < 10`, second as `(car$carro>=10) & (car$carr < 30)` and third as `car$carro >=30`.

This can be done easily without using `ifelse`.  We create a grouping index with `cut` by specifying the `breaks`.

```
  grp <- cut(car$carro, breaks=c(-Inf, 10, 30, Inf), right=FALSE, labels=FALSE)
```

Then, we use this numeric index to multiply the values with the 'carro' column.

```
  car$carro <- car$carro * c(0.5, 0.9, 1.5)[grp]
  car$carro
  #[1]  1.0  1.0 10.8  9.0 21.6 45.0 75.0 82.5 90.0
```